# How can I install i3 wm on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, macosx, i3-wm, vmware-fusion

I just followed the instructions [here](http://blog.hugochinchilla.net/2013/03/using-gnome-3-with-i3-window-manager/) to install i3 on a clean installed Ubuntu 13.10 on VMWare Fusion on OS X, however after selecting the i3 session from the login screen and logging in, all I see is a black screen and i3 key bindings don't do anything.

Also the instructions above installs an old version of i3.

How can I properly install the latest version of i3 (4.7) on Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the official i3 Ubuntu repository.  As root, run the following commands:

```
echo "deb http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/ $(lsb_release -c -s) universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install sur5r-keyring
apt-get update
apt-get install i3
```

The following Ubuntu versions are currently available: oneiric, precise, quantal, raring, saucy, trusty.  These instructions were taken from the [i3 docs](http://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html).

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible issues is that your Mod key does not get mapped correctly. Given thatr your host is OSX, the windows meta key may not exist in your keyboard mapping, or get intercepted by OSX. I would look into that first.

To double check that i3 is working, you can add startup apps to your i3 config, ie,

`echo 'exec i3-senstible-terminal' >> ~/.i3/config`